# SQL Server transpose rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, transpose

We have this table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 23 |
| 01-01-2020 | 24 |
| 01-01-2020 | 25 |
| 02-01-2020 | 11 |
| 02-01-2020 | 15 |

The requirement is to load the data in single row based on datetime column.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 02-01-2020 | 11 | 15 |  |

There can be up to 200 unique values against single datetime value.

How can this be achieved in a query?

I have tried using pivot but that results is aggregation which is not what I am after.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Please spell out your logic. What keeps your table in a certain order? Are you always splitting into 3 columns? Etc...

Comment: @DaleK the data needs to be loaded in excel by connecting to SQL server database which I do not have much control over. so we have to either write a SQL query or can also manipulate once the data available in excel.

Comment: I just asked you to show your best attempt so far... not sure your response is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have up to 200 hundred columns, I figured it would be best to number them.  You can expand up to the required number of columns

**Example**

```
Select *
  From (
        Select [Column A]
              ,[Column B]
              ,RN  = row_number() over (partition by [Column A] order by [Column B] )
         From  YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max([Column B]) for RN in ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10]
                                  ,[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20] 
                                  ,[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30] 
                                  ) ) Pvt
```